# Created MySQL view has low column length

Tags: mysql

I created a view that has a column with value length of over 1500 characters. But when the view is created, the column length is 343 characters.

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
SQL SECURITY INVOKER
VIEW `table_view` AS
    select
        concat("[",
            group_concat(
                concat(
                    '{"column1":"',`column1`,
                    '","column2":"',`column2`,
                    '","column3":"',`column3`,
                    '","column4":"',`column4`,
                    '","column5":"',`column5`,'"}'
                )
            ),
            "]"
        ) as `Big_column`
    from `Table`;
```

Is it somehow possible to increase it in the created view?

Answer (score 1):

The `GROUP_CONCAT()` function has a maximum result length controlled by a system variable called `group_concat_max_len`. You can read about that [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len).

You can adjust its length with

```
SET group_concat_max_len = 2048
```

or a similar command. Try putting in a larger value for that variable.

But your view tries to pack *all the rows of your table* into just one column. That seems strange.

Comment: It's not strange, I aimed at creating a JSON object. I checked `group_concat_max_len` and it's set at `1024`. Still, the length of the column is `343`.